# Ввод текста в разные поля типа EditText с кнопок в приложении

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

Есть в приложении несколько полей для ввода типа `EditText`:

```java
EditText in = findViewById(R.id.input);
EditText in2 = findViewById(R.id.input2);
```

Есть кнопки с текстовым значением типа:

```xml
android:text="0"
android:text="9"
```

У кнопки есть метод `onClick` с таким кодом:

```java
public void onNumberClick(View view) {
    Button button = (Button) view;
    in.append(button.getText());
}
```

Такой код позволяет вводить текст с кнопок только в одно конкретное поле, а мне нужно, чтобы можно было вводить в любое из имеющихся полей, которое я выделяю касанием. Как это сделать?

Comment: При касании - сохраните EditText в переменную. В методе нажатия кнопки - добавляйте текст именно в эту переменную.

Comment: Да, назначьте полям Edit методы onClick и там сохраняйте

Comment: А можно подробней? Я что-то не соображу, как такое написать. А onClick только у кнопок же может быть?

Comment: Так никто и не поможет?